# Cross Compile Raspberry with external libraries - copying of target folders

Tags: c, linux, gcc, cross-compiling, libraries

I am cross compiling *C-Code* from *Mac OS (Host)* for a *Raspberry Pi B+*, running *Raspbian Jessie, (Target)*. In order to link external libraries (*"WiringPi" and "pthread"*) during `make` I have used a somewhat lazy approach of copying the relevant folders containing headers and libraries from the target (i.e.  `/lib/`, `/usr/include/`, `/usr/lib/`, `/usr/local/lib/`, `/usr/local/include/`) to the host machine in advance.

My Cross GCC Compiler call is then modified as:

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -I"/Path/to/copy/of/target-folders/.../usr/local/include" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"main.d" -MT"main.o" -o "main.o" "../main.c"
```

The GCC Linker call is modified as:

```
arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc --sysroot=/Path/to/copy/of/target-folders/  -o "BlinkLedCrossCompile"  ./main.o   -lWiringPi -lpthread
```

This uses the copied target folders as sysroot. And so far, it works without any problems.

My question is: Is this a valid approach? Can I expect any problems further on?

Comment: [Here's a question I posted you might find interesting, if we get an answer that addresses it completely.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35705591/checkout-entire-os-apt-repo-for-cross-compiling).

Comment: If you look at Yocto's poky tool chain environment setup, you'll see they use exactly the same `--sysroot` approach.

Comment: @user3528438 May we please have an official URL for that? Sounds interesting. Thanks!